# Robot Framework don't find custom keyword from custom library

Tags: python, robotframework

I try to use a custom keyword by inherating selenium2library.
I've define this keyword in a `.py` file :

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
class TestLibrary(Selenium2Library):
    def storm_click(self, locator):
        submit_button = self._current_browser().find_element_by_class_name(locator)
        submit_button.click()
```

I have imported this custom keyword in my `.robot` test file using Library import:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  TestLibrary.py
```

When I execute robot

```
 robot tests/livestorm.robot
```

I've got this issue:

> No keyword with name 'storm click' found.

Have you any idea ton explain why robot framework don't find my custom keyword?

Comment: In which folder TestLibrary.py is placed?

Comment: What version of `Selenium2Library` are you using? Are you using the one based on SeleniumLibrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently using version 3 or greater of SeleniumLibrary. According to the [documentation for extending the library](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/extending/EXTENDING_SELENIUMLIBRARY.rst#general-principles-for-extending-seleniumlibrary), you must use the `@keyword` decorator for a method to be recognized as a keyword:

```
...
from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword
...
class TestLibrary(Selenium2Library):
    @keyword
    def storm_click(...):
        ...
```